# Is Possible to replace constant as input with auto incremet id in php

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on Online Exam module in laravel. In the Application, I store fill in the blanks (Multiple Fields in same question) answers in array format. I display fill in the blanks text box inputs using string replace function. How to display user inputed answers in fill in the blanks inputs.

When Create Question

[image]

Replace Constants

```
$question=str_replace('TEXT_FIELD_SMALL','<input type="text" name="answer[]">',$assessment->question->question_title);
```

Display in user view

[image]

Comment: By looking at your format, it looks like your answers will be in array. You can use something like `$answer = $request->answer; $answer [0], $answer[1]` ......

LIke `testef fdsfsf $answer[0] furthere text $answer[1]` I am just trying to share the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace` to achieve this as follows: The following answer is a sample related to your problem.

```
$answer = ["apple","ball","cat","doll"];
$text = "<p>It is a long TEXT_FIELD_SMALL_0 established fact TEXT_FIELD_SMALL_1 that a reader will TEXT_FIELD_SMALL_2 be distracted TEXT_FIELD_SMALL_3 by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here</p>";


$arr_to_replace =["TEXT_FIELD_SMALL_0","TEXT_FIELD_SMALL_1","TEXT_FIELD_SMALL_2","TEXT_FIELD_SMALL_3"];


$arr_replace_by = array();
foreach($answer as $ak => $av){
    $arr_replace_by[] = '<input type="text" value="'.$av.'"></input>';
}

$text = str_replace($arr_to_replace,$arr_replace_by,$text);
echo $text;
```

And in your case you can get `$answer` with `$request->answer`